# Why does the following code snippet returns None?

Tags: python

This should append the values in the list val from the new list I am creating here using range method.

```
val = [1, 2, 3,'time is', 10, 'up']
print val.extend(range(0,10))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.extend()` extends the list object *in place* and returns `None`.

You can print `val` after extending:

```
val.extend(range(0,10))
print val
```

or use concatenation:

```
print val + range(0, 10)
```

Comment: Yes what you suggested works here. What I don't understand is that once the extend method is executed on the list shouldn't it return the new extended list instead of none?

Comment: @nakkulable: No, because there is *no new list*. This is consistent with all other methods in the standard library. In place change? Return `None`. Produce a new value? Return that new value.

Comment: @nakkulable: `list.sort()`, `list.reverse()`, `list.append()`, `dict.update()`, `set.add()`, `set.discard()`, etc. etc. etc. all return `None`.